# Best way to store similar entries in sql where only one attribute differs

Tags: sql

Say I have a table with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE tasks (taskID TEXT, username TEXT, completed BOOL)
```

The tasks table is likely to grow large, and users will frequently be viewing their completed tasks, and, on separate occasions looking at their history of completed tasks.  This implementation would require an extra comparison every time a user wants to view one or the other (i.e. completed="true")

Is it better to have two tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ToDo (taskID TEXT, username TEXT)
CREATE TABLE completed(taskID TEXT, username TEXT)
```

Obviously, if this were the case, every time someone completes a task, a DELETE would happen in the ToDo table and an INSERT in the completed table.

I'm still a newbie in the ways of efficient SQL, so I don't know which of these implementations is better.  Any help?

Comment: If you are newbie, you should read something about normalization http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would keep them in one table.  If you are new to database design I would recommend reading up on database normalization.

One thing I would change is your use of `TEXT` for both taskId and username.  Are you sure that `int` and `varchar` would not be better suited for these columns?

Comment: It's possible he's using SQLite which uses TEXT as it's String-like data type. I believe it may accept varchar(n) but it ignores the limit imposed and ultimately converts it to TEXT. - This is specifically addressing the use of varchar for username, I agree about the INTEGER and taskId.

Comment: I don't either I'm just making an assumption from the Query provided.

Comment: "I would recommend reading up on database normalization" -- read up on POOD (Principle of Orthogonal Design) in addition to POFN (Principle of Full Normalization). The OP's latter design violates POOD but, assuming no nullable columns and keys, all proposed tables  tables would satisfy POFN, no?

Answer (score 0):

Your seconmd suggestion would be a nightmare to maintain and proably slower as well since you woudl have to both insert a new record and update or delete an old record for each action. If you want to simplify querying so you don't have to remember to get only the completed items or only the todo list, then put the queries in a view and use the views instead of directly querying the table.

As far as table size, modern datbases can have huge tables that can be particitoned if the size gets too big. So the fact that there will be lots of records is irrelevant inthe design. Large tables can generally operate very efficiently if they are proerly indexed.